# How to use inotifywait to call script that read from stdin

Tags: bash, files, stdin

I have this code:

```
inotifywait -m -e close_write src/lips.js ./test_port.scm | \
while read x; do ./test_port.scm; done
```

The problem is that my script read what inotifywait produce. So my question is: what is the proper way to run test_port.scm on each file change if that script read from stdin?

**UPDATE**:

So how this works look like this, I've made change it run the script to wait for input. but entering text don't work. And if I save again I've got:

```
./test_port.scm CLOSE_WRITE,CLOSE 
>>> ./test_port.scm CLOSE_WRITE,CLOSE
```

my code look like this:

```
(display (string-append ">>> " (read-line)))
(newline)
```

scheme code that read and print single line, the code is more complex under the hood, it's in fact Node.js + Readline that should read single line:

```
var interp = Interpreter('repl', {
    stdin: InputPort(function() {
        return new Promise(function(resolve) {
            rl = readline.createInterface({
                input: process.stdin,
                output: process.stdout
            });
            rl.question('', function(data) {
                resolve(data);
                rl.close();
            });
        });
    }),
```

I think that the issue is just with the `while read x;` that's why I've asked here.

**UPDATE:**

My actual issue is that I want to run script on each file change and the script need to read stdin, I actually don't care if it's inotifywait, but this is the only solution I've found that run on file change.

Comment: Please, add sample output of `inotifywait` when you write to the file

Comment: @GillesQuenot I've updated the code it show how it work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
inotifywait -m -e close_write src/lips.js ./test_port.scm |
    while read x; do
        ./test_port.scm </dev/tty
    done
```

Answer (score 4):

The general way is to wrap your whole pipeline as a list, duplicate the file descriptor used as its standard input and redirect the standard input of the command in your loop's body to make it read from that new one:

```bsh
{
  inotifywait -m -e close_write src/lips.js ./test_port.scm |
    while read x; do
      ./test_port.scm 0<&3
    done
} 3<&0
```

This is basically equivalent to using `/dev/tty`, as [Hauke Laging's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/594459/315749) does, but it also allows the outer standard input not to be a terminal.

Note that, however, this solution requires filenames not to contain newline characters: they would make the loop's body run more than once for each event (with a spurious value of the `x` variable). Depending on your use case, it may be fine for you to prevent `inotifywait` from printing filenames by means of its `--format` option.

Answer (score 2):

Just found this at SuperUser [How to execute a command whenever a file changes?](https://superuser.com/a/181543/50659)

There is alternative call with:

```
while inotifywait -q -e close_write myfile.py; do ./myfile.py; done
```

Or, to make `inotifywait` print nothing:

```
while inotifywait -qq -e ...
```